# How to access user-supplied command-line options in Tcl?

Tags: tcl

in the command line i m giving input as

> filename option

here option starting with hyphen.

how to pass command line arguments starts with -

Answer (score 3):

The list of all the arguments passed to the process hosting your Tcl interpreter can be accessed using the [global variable `argv`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M45), which you can iterate over and inspect.

Special packages implementing ready-made solutions for "declarative" parsing of command-line arguments exist, with [`cmdline`](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/cmdline.html) being one example.  Also [search the wiki for alternatives](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/search?S=getopt).

Comment: The `argc` global can also be useful occasionally, but it's really just the same as `llength $argv`…

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need the cmdline package from tcllib.

Documentation is here

http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/cmdline.html

Joachim